# Display correct sum in reportviewer when the view is filtered

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm quite new to the ReportViewer component and I've been struggling with this seemingly simple task for quite a while.

Basically, I have designed a simple report like this (self-explanatory, I think):
[image: Report]
The expression for the sum is

```
=Sum(Fields!PriceTotal.Value)
```

Now, my problem is, I have a **filter** applied to this report. The view is filtered correctly (some rows are hidden), but the sum includes the hidden rows as well and displays the wrong number.

How should I change the above expression to return **correct results**? I only want **a sum of all visible (filtered) rows**.

BTW, I can't change the datasource, filtering must be done in the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you have condition to hide some rows. Apply the same condition to Sum:

```
=Sum(IIF(<your hide condition>, 0, Fields!PriceTotal.Value))
```